# Put Links at the End of a Page ( Drupal)

Tags: drupal

Is there a module in Drupal that allows me to put link at the end of a page?

[http://lh6.ggpht.com/_SDci0Pf3tzU/Sfm7vF_MSiI/AAAAAAAAEtY/VX3BXaMOfSM/s400/linksatend.jpg](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/WDqZY0HqvyVP9bbck2VSUA?feat=embedwebsite)

I tried to use menu and put it as a block at the footer, but the menu items are arranged vertically, instead of horizontally.

Is there anyway to do it without ( preferably) touching the CSS and HTML?

Answer (score 0):

changing the menu items from vertically to horizontally is a matter of 1 or 2 css rules. which is why i doubt that there is a module for this. if you would post a link to your site, or the html + css, i could help with the css.

Comment: the menu items there (Education, Entertainment, Paragon Mall, Forum, Property List) *are* arranged horizontally. what exactly do you want?

Comment: I think he probably refers to the links currently in the simplemenu: Education
FOE FIT Entertainment Paragon Mall Forum Property List

Answer (score 0):

Links at the end of the page can be controlled by a few different things.

First, check the Blocks administration and see if there is a content area for the footer. Maybe there is a block there that is controlling these links.

Next, depending on well the theme is built, check the configuration options under Admin > Site Building > Themes > Conigure > (Your theme). Many have options to change what links display in the footer.

Lastly, check the page.tpl.php. They could also be hard-coded in the template (which is bad) and edited from there.

In terms of answering your question about 'a module to alter links', you can see that since the links can be controlled from different places, a module just for this purpose would be pointless. The correct way is to set the appropriate options in template.php so it can be configured in your theme settings.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck using the [Nice Menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) module - it's intended to create animated menus but if you give it a flat menu tree, it might be close enough to what you want.  If that doesn't work, there's about 100 [modules dealing with navigation](http://drupal.org/project/modules?page=1&filters=tid%3A124&solrsort=sort_title%20asc).

Still, the best way would be to place the menu's block in the footer and modify the theme to [flatten it with CSS](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+list+menu+horizontal&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't won't to touch the theme, maybe because you're using an unmodified contrib theme, you can use either of two approaches:

- create the block by hand as a custom HTML block, which gives you full control over the contents. The main downside is that you'll have to maintain it by hand instead of using admin/build/menus
- create a PHP block, either custom (boo !) or in your site-specific module (better), to generate a block with markup appropriate for the theme you're using, based on the actual primary links, which you obtain from [menu_primary_links()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/menu_primary_links/6). Downside it that you have to create a site module if you don't already have one, or that you'll have to enable the PHP filter if you create it as a custom block.

This being said, I think you'd still be better off modifying the theme if it's a custom one, or creating a sub-theme for the theme you're using if it's a contributed one. It will be less work and, this being a matter of appearance, falls rather in theme scope than in module scope.